# The default text for the "Ask question" title box

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was about to post a question, when I noticed the default text in the title box was somewhat grammatically incorrect:

> What's your creation and solving of puzzles question? Be specific.

I think we should change this a little, to something like

> What's your question about the creation and solving of puzzles? Be specific.

Any input?

Answer (score 5):

Let's make this simple:

> What's your puzzling question? Be specific.

Note: Ambiguity pleases me.

I actually think the current version is fine in terms of clarity and grammar. But it's a bit stilted.

Comment: I like your proposed wording better, but [I don't think we can change it](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99/10), unless you have unicorn-dusted inside SE info I don't know about? :)

Comment: @WendiKidd: Yeah. I think you are correct. We are probably stuck with the current version, then.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question about another site's default text box once, and I don't think it can be changed. I figured out that the way the code currently works, there's a canned description for what every site is about ("English language learning", "creation and solving of puzzles", "programming") and it gets fed into a preset string that looks something like this:

```
print("What's your %@ question? Be specific.", site.descStrShort);
```

And then I asked an SE staff member if I was right about this, and they said yes and it wasn't likely to change. So I think that's probably where we're at for now :)

Comment: Shame, I like both other suggestions.